# Using azure blob storage for spark checkpointing

Tags: java, apache-spark, azure-blob-storage, spark-structured-streaming

I am trying to use azure storage as checkpoint location in my spark structured streaming application.
I have seen few articles which talks about reading/writing to azure storage, but I have not seen anyone explaining about using azure storage as checkpoint location. Following is my simple code, reading from one kafka topic and writing back to another topic, added checkpoint location.

```
SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local[*]");
    conf.set(
            "fs.azure.account.key.<storage-name>.blob.core.windows.net",
            "<storage-key>");
    conf.set("fs.wasbs.impl", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.NativeAzureFileSystem");
    SparkSession spark = SparkSession.builder().appName("app-name").config(conf).getOrCreate();

    Dataset<Row> df = spark
            .readStream()
            .format("kafka")
            .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092")
            .option("subscribe", "input")
            .load();

    StreamingQuery ds = df
            .selectExpr("CAST(key AS STRING)", "CAST(value AS STRING)")
            .writeStream()
            .format("kafka")
            .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092")
            .option("topic", "output")
            .option("checkpointLocation", "wasbs://<container-name>@<storage-account-name>.blob.core.windows.net/<directory-name>")
            .start();

    ds.awaitTermination();
```

Azure connection details are correct. When I run this application, I could see one file(metadata) getting created at the specified azure storage location. However, app crashes after few seconds. Below is the exception.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Self-suppression not permitted
        at java.lang.Throwable.addSuppressed(Throwable.java:1043)
        at java.io.FilterOutputStream.close(FilterOutputStream.java:159)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.NativeAzureFileSystem$NativeAzureFsOutputStream.close(NativeAzureFileSystem.java:818)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSDataOutputStream$PositionCache.close(FSDataOutputStream.java:72)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSDataOutputStream.close(FSDataOutputStream.java:106)
        at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.closeQuietly(IOUtils.java:339)
        at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.closeQuietly(IOUtils.java:298)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamMetadata$.write(StreamMetadata.scala:85)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution$$anonfun$2.apply(StreamExecution.scala:124)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution$$anonfun$2.apply(StreamExecution.scala:122)
        at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.<init>(StreamExecution.scala:122)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.<init>(MicroBatchExecution.scala:49)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.StreamingQueryManager.createQuery(StreamingQueryManager.scala:258)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.StreamingQueryManager.startQuery(StreamingQueryManager.scala:299)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.DataStreamWriter.start(DataStreamWriter.scala:296)
        at com.test.Test.main(Test.java:73)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Stream is already closed.
        at com.microsoft.azure.storage.blob.BlobOutputStreamInternal.close(BlobOutputStreamInternal.java:332)
        at java.io.FilterOutputStream.close(FilterOutputStream.java:159)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.NativeAzureFileSystem$NativeAzureFsOutputStream.close(NativeAzureFileSystem.java:818)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSDataOutputStream$PositionCache.close(FSDataOutputStream.java:72)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSDataOutputStream.close(FSDataOutputStream.java:106)
        at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implClose(StreamEncoder.java:320)
        at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.close(StreamEncoder.java:149)
        at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.close(OutputStreamWriter.java:233)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.WriterBasedJsonGenerator.close(WriterBasedJsonGenerator.java:883)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._configAndWriteValue(ObjectMapper.java:3561)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.writeValue(ObjectMapper.java:2909)
        at org.json4s.jackson.Serialization$.write(Serialization.scala:27)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamMetadata$.write(StreamMetadata.scala:78)
        ... 9 more
```

Let me know If anything needs to be configured to enable azure storage as checkpoint location or any version conflicts creating this problem.

```
Spark: 2.3.0
hadoop-azure : 2.7
azure-storage : 8.0
```